# prevent to load multiple time in vuejs using load-google-maps-api

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to load two google map instances dynamically on a single page but it fetches below errors.

> You have included the Google Maps JavaScript API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.

providing below code for more help as I am using the load-google-maps-api node_module.

```
 googleMapInit () {

            let self = this,
                mapElement = this.$refs.canvasy;

            loadGoogleMapsAPI({
                key: this.gmk,
                language: this.language
            })
            .then( googleApi => {

                self.contextMarkerLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng( self.contextMarkerCoords.lat, self.contextMarkerCoords.lng );

                self.googleMap = new google.maps.Map( mapElement , {
                    disableDefaultUI: true,
                    styles: MapStylesObj.styles,
                    zoom: self.googleMapZoom,
                    minZoom: self.googleMapMinZoom,
                    center: self.contextMarkerLatLng
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using `load-google-maps-api-2`:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/load-google-maps-api-2

It is built on top of `load-google-maps-api`, so should work the same and includes the following feature:

> Added check whether API is already loaded. (Google API writes warnings into console when they are loaded multiple times.)